# WebEngineView: how to highlight search results?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, qt, qml

I have a case, that I cannot resolve: I have **WebEngineView(QML)** in my app. I load some html to that WebEngineView(email body). I need to highlight some words in case if user applied a search tag before. I tried to use it with replace using regex **(searchTag + "(?!([^<]+)?>")** to ignore words in tags and raplace a found substring with **mark tag** from html for text highlighting. However, it's not working for words like "height", "width" etc, it corrupts entire document.

I was trying to find a way to resolve my issue in Qt docs but didn't have a success. Is there any way to resolve my issue? Perhaps, javascript?

Comment: As I  remember from my web expirience, you have to loop through DOM tree nodes, not the html source.

Comment: @fobis , awesome! So basically looping through DOM tree nodes will let me modify only text within tags, right?

Comment: Use [mark.js](https://markjs.io) - a JavaScript keyword highlighter

Comment: Yeah, WebEngine allows you to run custom script. So you just can write it by yourself(10-15 lines I guess) or use external script as @dude adviced.

Comment: @folibis , how do I use custom .js scripts for WebEngineView? Not for QML, but for WebView.

Comment: @MaksymBulhakov check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#user-scripts